# Performance of the fuzzy c-means clustering algorithm

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have implemented a genetic algorithm for a fuzzy c-means clustering in Matlab. Its performance should be apriori better than that of the classic fuzzy c-means (fcm function in matlab). However, on all the classical datasets I am comparing them, both algorithms converge to the same value of the objective function.

My question is the following: is it just my bad luck, or FCM usually converges to the global minimum? Are there any datasets known when FCM shows suboptimal performance?

Thanks,

Comment: This might be better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ since it is more about methods than specific code.

Comment: Thanks, please close if unappropriate here.

Comment: It depends a lot on your data sets. On a reasonably easy data set, it should converge to the global minimum (in particular, when there is no other local minimum ...)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, Yes, that is what I am asking in fact. Is it known that for some sets, number of clusters or the dimension of the feature space - objective function of a fcm has a single minimum or the attracting set of other local minimums have small measure?

Comment: Well, if $k = n$ and there are no duplicate points, FCM definitely should have a single minimum... while on uniform data with $k << n$, I assume there would be serveral local minima. Except that there is no sensible clustering with $k > 1$ at all.